Log shows getShouldDeclineWhiteColor false in loop
I am coding an Android (Java) application and whenever I navigate to a view, the logcat shows this message in an infinite loop:

2024-11-18 13:12:28.227 19514-19514 Drawable                com.company.project          D  getShouldDeclineWhiteColor false

I have tried to look for this method throughout the project but I can't seem to find it, so I thought it might be a Drawable method. I had no luck finding what it does or when it is called, much less why it is caught in a loop. I have only found a couple of logs of other projects on Google that contain the name of the method, so I think that means it is not created in my project.
So my question is: what does this method do and when is it called?
Thank you for the answers.
